# Changing the state of another entity into the constructor method

Tags: python, design-patterns, constructor, pyglet

I have a Clock class who inherites from pyglet.clock.Clock and behaves like a Singleton.

Into the constructor method I have the following line:

```
pyglet.clock.set_default(self)
```

Who changes the state of the default clock of pyglet, setting my Clock object as the default clock.

The constructor method leaves the Clock object into a valid state (without this line in the constructor the clock don't tick!).

**Changing another entity state in the constructor:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyglet

import singleton

class Clock(pyglet.clock.Clock):
    __metaclass__ = singleton.Singleton

    def __init__(self):
        super(Clock, self).__init__()

        pyglet.clock.set_default(self)

class Test(object):
    def update(self, dt):
        print dt

w = pyglet.window.Window()
@w.event
def on_draw():
    w.clear()

t = Test()

c = Clock()
c.schedule_interval(t.update, 1/60.0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

On the other hand I can do:

**Calling pyglet.clock.set_default outside of the constructor:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyglet

import singleton

class Clock(pyglet.clock.Clock):
    __metaclass__ = singleton.Singleton

    def __init__(self):
        super(Clock, self).__init__()

class Test(object):
    def update(self, dt):
        print dt

w = pyglet.window.Window()
@w.event
def on_draw():
    w.clear()

t = Test()

c = Clock()
pyglet.clock.set_default(self)
c.schedule_interval(t.update, 1/60.0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

In this case the call:

```
pyglet.clock.set_default(self)
```

Is outside of the constructor method and then the constructor method don't change the state of another entity.

**The questions:**

1. What is the solution more elegant or pythonic?
2. Is any of these solutions a best practice?
3. How do you resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you subclassing pyglet's Clock?

Comment: @WinstonEwert I want to let the code more clean if I have to add more functionality to the class in the future and let only the more primitive objects modules interacts with the pyglet library.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a singleton should be a module, not a class. There's no good reason to define a class for that. That's what's going on in pyglet's case with `pyglet.clock`. If you want to define your own version you should do something like:

```
# myclock.py

from pyglet.clock import *
```

Then you can add functions/etc to that module to get additional behavior. This way you don't even need to call the set_default function.

Comment: I think it is a design question. Because without a metaclass Singleton you can call the Clock class and create another Clock instance.

Comment: @SuperUser, sure, you could design it so that you could create many Clock instances. I'd be all in favor of that. But that's not what you did.

Comment: Yes, but I point that with your proposed solution: A subclass Clock (without a Singleton restriction) and a variable module clock you are still having a non-Singleton object.

Comment: @SuperUser, I'm confused. What do you think my proposed solution is?

Comment: You proposed the pyglet approach, but if I do from pyglet.clock import * I still can call Clock() and create another Clock instance.

Comment: @SuperUser, is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @WinstonEwert on usage of singletons in Python (having module singletons is Pythonic because their code is executed only once per program run, and modules can be imported from other modules which should have access to this singleton), if the program is simple and will not be expanded upon, I would go with your second version, which can be fixed in a much simpler way by replacing

```
pyglet.clock.set_default(self)
```

with

```
pyglet.clock.set_default(c)
```

`self` is (by convention) the first argument of every bound method that represents the object on which this method was called, thus the calling expression has no meaning outside of your class and should fail (because `self` should be undefined at that point).  To point to your constructed object of class `Class` you may use the name you bound it to, that is, `c`.